# python dictionary search, compare, and calculate values

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have two dictionaries like below:

```
dict1 = {1: (7, 5), 2: (5, 9), 3: (3, 4)}

dict2 = {1: (9, 12), 2: (6, 11), 3: (7, 19)}
```

Dictionaries can have unlimited number of keys perhaps 10k and every key is unique positive number. I need three separated functions which will return a single key with:

func1 ) highest difference between second value position, which is key 3 in example above 19-4=15.

func2 ) highest difference between first value position, which is also key 3 in example above 7-3=4.

func3 ) highest difference as sum of key values, which is key 3 again because (7+19)-(3+4)=19

Both dictionaries have the same keys and dict2 can have the same or higher values. If function find more then one key with the same result it will return higher key.

Comment: @RyPeck makes a good point, we need something to go on unless you expect somebody to write the code for you.

Comment: well I'm not sure how to start, I don't asking for the finished solution just for a good starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something simple like a single traversal of the dictionaries.  If they have the same keys, you can just iterate over 1 dict.

```
def func(d1, d2):
    m = (0, 0)
    for k in d1:
        res = abs(d1[k][1] - d2[k][1]) #func1
        #res = abs(d1[k][0] - d2[k][0]) # func2
        #res = abs(sum(d1[k]) - sum(d2[k])) # func3
        if res > m[1]: m = (k, res)
    return m[0]
```

Comment: Simple and very effective. Thank you Bill